# Increase the RSA Encryption block size to 512 in Swift

Tags: swift, security, encryption, aes

In Swift I want to encrypt my text and send to server. I wrote below code to encrypt. 
I'm using `SecKeyAlgorithm.rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA512` algorithm

```
func encrypt(_ plainText: String) throws -> String {
    let plainData = plainText.data(using: .utf8)!
    let cfData: CFData = plainData as NSData as CFData
            
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(publicKey, .encrypt, algorithm) else {
        fatalError("Can't use algorithm with this key!")
    }
            
    guard let cipherData = SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(publicKey, algorithm, cfData, &error) else {
        throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
    }
    
    // Convert the encrypted data to a base64 string so it can be easily transmitted or stored
    let cipherText = (cipherData as Data).base64EncodedString()
    return cipherText
}
```

I printed the block size using `SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey)` and its printing 256.

The code works good if my plain text passed to the function is less than 256 bytes/characters. But my text length is more than 300 bytes. How can I increase the size of the encryption text to support this?

Comment: You should not be encrypting data with RSA. Generally, you only encrypt keys that are in turn used for symmetrical encryption, with RSA. Then you encrypt the data using your symmetrical algorithm with a suitable mode of operation such as GCM, and you will have no limits on the size of the data you can encrypt. The title of your post is misleading, and may also indicate some part of the source of the problem. You're not using AES, you're using RSA.

Comment: The maximum amount of data that can be encrypted with RSA is given by the key size minus a value determined by the padding. For OAEP, this value depends on the digest. With a 4096 bits key and OAEP with SHA256, a maximum of 512 - 66 = 446 bytes can be encrypted, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42097).

Comment: @Topaco For RSA I can't provide the key size.

Comment: The key size is specified when the RSA key is generated (if it is not explicitly specified, a default value is usually applied, e.g. 2048 bits).